# android recyclerview center horizontal items

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, cardview

how to implement this design? [design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wJUYH.jpg)
My current implementation of the design looks like this, how to remove black spaces?.
[currentImplementation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MbSDD.png)
my current code of recycler view

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/gesture_layout"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="260dp"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:background="@color/transparent"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:clipToPadding="false"
                android:visibility="visible"
                />

        </FrameLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```

my current code of cardView

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/black"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    >

    <!-- A CardView that contains a GifImageView -->
    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/card_view"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="68dp"
        android:layout_height="68dp"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="0dp"
        card_view:cardMaxElevation="0dp"
        card_view:cardElevation="0dp"
        card_view:cardBackgroundColor="@color/tab_selected"
        >

        <pl.droidsonroids.gif.GifImageView
            android:id="@+id/emoji"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/transparent"
            />
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Try adding android:layout_width="68dp" and  android:layout_height="68dp" to your LinearLayout

Comment: I added android:layout_width="68dp" and android:layout_height="68dp" to my LinearLayout but the spaces not remove, now the spaces are white

Comment: post your java codes for this recyclerview

Comment: mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) layout.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
mRecyclerView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
mRecyclerView.addItemDecoration(new SpacesItemDecoration(10, context));mLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(context, AppContext.getInstance().numberOfEmojisPerRow , GridLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);
mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
emojiAdapter = new EmojiAdapter(tabMenu, context, emojiClickedCallBack);
mRecyclerView.setAdapter(emojiAdapter);

Comment: use mRecyclerView.addItemDecoration(new SpacesItemDecoration(1, context)); or comment out this line

Comment: The item decorator only add bottom space to the items
 @Override
    public void getItemOffsets(Rect outRect, View view,
                               RecyclerView parent, RecyclerView.State state) {
        super.getItemOffsets(outRect, view, parent, state);
        int outRectBottom = Util.pxToDp(10, context);
        outRect.bottom = outRectBottom;
    }

Comment: add card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="false" to your cardview xml

Comment: card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="false" looks same

Answer (score 0):

**1.** Add `android:layout_width="68dp"` and `android:layout_height="68dp"` to your `LinearLayout`.

**2.** Remove line `mRecyclerView.addItemDecoration(new SpacesItemDecoration(10, context));` or use smaller gap.

**3.** Add attribute `card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="false"` to `CardView`.

**Try this:**

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="68dp"
    android:layout_height="68dp"
    android:background="@color/black"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">

    <!-- A CardView that contains a GifImageView -->
    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/card_view"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="0dp"
        card_view:cardMaxElevation="0dp"
        card_view:cardElevation="0dp"
        card_view:cardBackgroundColor="@color/tab_selected"
        card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="false">

        <pl.droidsonroids.gif.GifImageView
            android:id="@+id/emoji"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/transparent"/>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
</LinearLayout>
```